# Rails mailer mimepart visible as text in message body

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, mime, mailer

I'm sending test mail using ActionMailer. The template is being rendered and mail is being delivered fine. The only problem is the mimepart and other header data is displayed by Google in message body.

Here is the code that mails..

```
def testing

    mail(:to => "apoorvparijat@gmail.com",:subject => "html mailer", :content_type => "text/html") do |format|
          format.html { render 'testing' }
          format.text { render :text => "bing" }
    end
end
```

and Here's the email received.

```
----==_mimepart_508fd46252b8c_8023fe595835ad0479a6 Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 18:51:38 +0530     
Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <508fd46254ea7_8023fe595835ad0480b8@Apoorv-Parijats-MacBook-Pro-2.local.mail> 
bing ----==_mimepart_508fd46252b8c_8023fe595835ad0479a6 Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 18:51:38 
+0530 Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding:  
7bit Content-ID: <508fd46256465_8023fe595835ad04819c@Apoorv-Parijats-MacBook-Pro-
2.local.mail> Hi bing
column 1    column 2
----==_mimepart_508fd46252b8c_8023fe595835ad0479a6--
```

Output of the console -

```
 Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.2)
 1.9.3-p125 :001 > RankMailer.testing.deliver
 I, [2012-10-30T18:51:38.331238 #2050]  INFO -- :   Rendered rank_mailer/testing.html.erb           
 (1.8ms)
 I, [2012-10-30T18:51:38.333117 #2050]  INFO -- :   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
 I, [2012-10-30T18:51:45.824962 #2050]  INFO -- : 
 Sent mail to apoorvparijat@gmail.com (7484ms)
 D, [2012-10-30T18:51:45.825125 #2050] DEBUG -- : Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 18:51:38 +0530
 From: admin@rankdemon.com
 To: apoorvparijat@gmail.com
        Message-ID: <508fd462572ec_8023fe595835ad0482c0@Apoorv-Parijats-MacBook-Pro-2.local.mail>
    Subject: html mailer
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/html;
     charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



    ----==_mimepart_508fd46252b8c_8023fe595835ad0479a6
    Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 18:51:38 +0530
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain;
     charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Content-ID: <508fd46254ea7_8023fe595835ad0480b8@Apoorv-Parijats-MacBook-Pro-2.local.mail>

    bing

    ----==_mimepart_508fd46252b8c_8023fe595835ad0479a6
    Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 18:51:38 +0530
    Mime-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/html;
     charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Content-ID: <508fd46256465_8023fe595835ad04819c@Apoorv-Parijats-MacBook-Pro-2.local.mail>

    Hi bing

    <table style="border:1px solid red">
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    ----==_mimepart_508fd46252b8c_8023fe595835ad0479a6--

     => #<Mail::Message:70255316899740, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 18:51:38 +0530>, <From: admin@rankdemon.com>, <To: apoorvparijat@gmail.com>, <Message-ID: <508fd462572ec_8023fe595835ad0482c0@Apoorv-Parijats-MacBook-Pro-2.local.mail>>, <Subject: html mailer>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't specify `:content_type => "text/html"` in your mail method. Since you're using format block, rails will automatically pick up mime type.

**MORE DETAILS:**

Try this to send out multipart email (ie. both html and text formats of email). Notice the order of formats.

```
mail(:to => "apoorvparijat@gmail.com", :subject => "html mailer") do |format|
    format.text { render :text => "bing" }
    format.html { render 'testing' }
end
```

Comment: The problem was the `:content_type`. I removed `format.text` and left the `:content_type` as it is. HTML email is being sent without any error. Though I'm yet to figure out that what `:content_type` should be used if I've to send the fallback text as well in the email.

Comment: You can user multiple formats. Then Mailer will create multipart email, with all user formats. User's client or web interface will pick appropriate format automatically. To use more formats, remove the ":content_type" parameter. I just added example to the reply. Take a look at this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-multipart-emails) for more details and ordering info.